# Covariance of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that we have two *independent* random variables $X$ and $Y$. We are interested in the following covariance:

$$\mathbb{C}ov\left[X,\mathbb{I}\left[X+Y>0\right]\right],
$$

where $\mathbb{I}[\cdot]$ is an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Can we conclude that this covariance is positive? [This paper](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schmidt/dsvm/dsvm2003-4.pdf) shows that if $Y=0$, the result is true (the indicator function is a monotonically increasing function).

Is it also true in this more general case?

Comment: I think where it says "positive" you mean "non-negative"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance (assuming it exists) is nonnegative by the FKG inequality, since $x$ and ${\mathbb I}[x + y > 0]$ are nondecreasing on $\mathbb R^2$.